# Differences between files generated with python of windows and python of cygwin

Tags: python, diff, difflib

I have a script to generate files with python, in some cases, the script is executed with the python of in windows and in other cases with the python of cygwin

the text of the files is the same but if I use difflib,

```
gen_file_data = open(gen_file)
base_file_data = open(base_file)
gen_file_content = gen_file_data.read().splitlines(True)
base_file_content = base_file_data.read().splitlines(True)
gen_file_data.close()
base_file_data.close()
diff = difflib.unified_diff(gen_file_content, base_file_content, n=0)
diff = ''.join(diff)
```

the files are different.

And, if I use md5 get diferent hash.

```
import hashlib
base_md5 = hashlib.md5(base_file_content).hexdigest()
gen_md5 = hashlib.md5(gen_file_content).hexdigest()
print gen_md5, base_md5
```

If I compare the files with `kdiff3` I get

```
Files A and B have equal text, but are not binary equal.
```

how I can comparate the text diferences between two files?, one generated with python of windows and other generated with python of windows.

Comment: Do you think it might be end-of-line? Windows uses '\r\n', whereas unix (which cygwin emulates) uses '\n'

Comment: @user590028 thanks, I add `.replace('\r\n', '\n')` to file content and this fix the problem.

Comment: @user590028 please, you can put your comment as  answer  ? for close the question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely end-of-line encoding. Windows uses '\r\n', whereas unix (which cygwin emulates) uses '\n'